# memcached with load ("node") balancers in linode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I'm trying to setup a node balancer with 2 application servers and 1 db servers. The application servers "talk" to the db server. And web requests first go through my node balancer (which distribute the work to the application servers). What I want to do now is to add memcached to the mix. If I want to add a new VPS to serve memcached, how can I configure this to make sure each application server cache data and get it back properly? The details of how such a setup would work is just a big foggy to me right now. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: by the way, I'm using linode and this is for a rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a high level what you want to do is setup your memcached cluster in front of database server. In you application you will add a memcached client to talk to memcached and your code will look something like this.

```
itm = memcached_client.get("key");
if (itm != null) {
  return itm;
}else {
  query = database_client.doQuery("Some Query");
  memcached_client.set("some_key", query);
  return query;
}
```

Your question is quite general so I'm not sure if there is something more specific that your having issues with.

Comment: yep, I know it's general. I'm just trying to wrap my head around the entire process, but your answer clarified things a lot for me. Thank you.